# MacOS Sierra Keyboard layout changes to Windows keyboard layout in Microsoft Remote Desktop

Tags: mac, keyboard, macos, remote-desktop, pc

I use the most recent version of Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection [v8.0.40] to connect to my Windows PC at work. When the connection establishes on the Windows 10 environment, Mac's keyboard layout doesn't work. Thus I have to use different combinations of the keys to work on the remote desktop. It is very annoying as I am very much used to using command instead of ctrl and could not remap my keyboard layout. Is there anyone who can suggest a fix?

The previous versions of RDC app were working fine and I Mac's Keyboard layout was operating well on Windows platform. Following is a list of details on my two devices:

The remote Windows:
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 10.0.10586 Build 10586

Mac OS:
10.12.5

Answer (score 1):

There are currently two versions of RDC available; release 8.0.xx & beta 8.2.xx - If one doesn't behave as you'd expect, I'd try the other.

Beta from [Microsoft Technet blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/03/30/remote-desktop-client-preview-for-mac-supports-multiple-monitors-and-more/)

More specifically, the Release version has *always* made you switch to using Windows standard  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>   <kbd>X</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>  etc
The Beta allows you to use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>C</kbd>   <kbd>X</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>  & even though still a beta, is actually better in many respects.